# Jenkins Git Publisher tag not picking up environment variables

Tags: git, jenkins

I've been setting up my jenkins windows service to build all my projects, and have now got to the stage where I want jenkins to create a tag to indicate a successful build.

I'm attempting this as a post build step using the Git Publisher module.

My settings are as follows:

- Push Only If Build Succeeds - Yes
- Merge Results: No
- Tag to push: %BUILD_NUMBER%
- Create new tag: Yes
- Target remote name: origin/master

The log file tells me that it's

```
Pushing tag %BUILD_NUMBER% to repo origin/master
```

and that is what I see within my git repository. I have tried other environment variables to no avail. The help says:

```
Environment variables may be used in the tag name - they will be replaced at build time.
```

which isn't what I'm seeing. What I'm trying to achieve is that I push a tag which is named after the successful build number.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works if I use $BUILD_NUMBER instead of %BUILD_NUMBER%

Comment: Jane is right. %BUILD_NUMBER% works only within the "Execute Windows Batch" portion of Jenkins. The rest of it uses Linux style variables - $BUILD_NUMBER