# Jenkins Git Publisher tag not detecting environment variables

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

In my Jenkins bash script, I export the following environment variable:

```
export TAG_NAME=v$LIVE_VERSION.$LIVE_BUILD
```

In the Git publisher section, I am trying to create a tag with the tag name field filled with `$TAG_NAME`, but it is trying to create a tag literally with the name `$TAG_NAME` instead of substituting in the value for the environment variable.

Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694052/jenkins-git-publisher-tag-not-picking-up-environment-variables) SO question, as the answer works for the asker, but for some reason does not work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you started bash via an "Execute shell" step in Jenkins?

The problem here is that shell environment variables are not the same as the environment variables used by Jenkins. While you can use certain Jenkins variables in bash (go to `<your_jenkins_server_address>/env-vars.html/` to see which ones), you cannot do the reverse. Any variable you set in bash is gone when bash finishes.

A workaround is to write your tags to file and read them in using the Jenkins
[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). The plugin can read a properties file and add all properties as Jenkins environment variables.

For example, bash writing to file:

```
echo TAG_NAME=v$LIVE_VERSION.$LIVE_BUILD > tags.txt
```

EnvInject plugin reading the file and injecting its properties so Jenkins can use it:

[image: Inject environment variable]

Comment: Funny, I ended up using this method as a solution before you wrote the answer.